How to run music using R.raw.music1 in another thread or background?
I want to run music in background or another thread not on main thread. when i continuedly click on button and call music method then start music without any delay and without freezing main Thread.
please suggest perfect way for doing this.( AsyncTask is not working)
public static void wrongMove() {
        if (music) {
            backgroundHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (MainActivity.music) {
                        final MediaPlayer musicPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.mainRelative.getContext(), R.raw.wrong_move);
                        musicPlayer.start();
                        musicPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer::release);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }


You can use Executors or simply spawn a thread and play from there (which i don't recommend)

I wouldn't recommend doing this, as MediaPlayer instances should always be made on the same thread. As shown in the Docs

MediaPlayer is not thread-safe. Creation of and all access to player instances should be on the same thread. If registering callbacks, the thread must have a Looper.

As MediaPlayer already uses it's own native thread for playing the audio, I don't see why you would want to create a new thread in the first place. As you can see from the source code
public void start() throws IllegalStateException {
    stayAwake(true);
    _start();
}

private native void _start() throws IllegalStateException;

This is because

Android includes Stagefright, a media playback engine at the native level that has built-in software-based codecs for popular media formats

Further reading
